# CSS not clearing div elements on mobile / responsive design

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

We are working on a project and cant seem to get the responsive divs to behave correctly. They are running into other div elements on the page instead of clearing them. We are using bootstrap 4.3.1 and we need some help

Here's [the webpage](https://www.ibusiness-directory.ca/listings/restaurants) so you can see what's happening.

Any help would be appreciated!

```css
/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column_left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #E6E6E8;
}

.column_right {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #E6E6E8;
}

.setADS {
  float: right;
  margin: 0px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.setADS:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column_left,
  .column_right {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="setADS">
  <div class="column_left" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column_right" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column_left" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column_right" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 4</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Floats are an outdated and often frustrating technique. I suggest using an alternative layout strategy such as inline-block, flexbox, or grid.

Comment: Have you tried working with flexbox instead of float?

Comment: Also, **[Bootstrap provides all of this already](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/).** Why are you writing your own alongside it? That's the whole point of using a library. I strongly suggest skimming over the entire documentation for Bootstrap to become familiar with what it provides.

Comment: You should use grid or flexbox

Comment: Finally, don't use inline styles. They're a giant pain for you and all those who come after. Use custom classes where needed, but again, [Bootstrap provides](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/colors/#background-color).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your page is not ok. That's why you are having issues also if you solve this problem you will have problems afterward as well I Will give you a basic structure from where you can start or maybe put your code blocks in that structure.

Also in column1 column2 ... do not use custom styling if you want to remove spacing between the blocks/columns just use the predefined class in bootstrap with row class which is **no-gutter**

After your header put this structure.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
      ... put your listing here.
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <!--Below is the solution for your divs column1, column2 .....-->
    <div class="row no-gutter">
      <div class="col-md-6">column 1</div>
      <div class="col-md-6">column 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row no-gutter">
      <div class="col-md-6">column 3</div>
      <div class="col-md-6">column 4</div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for us, I am still working out a few bugs but appreciate the quick response from everyone.

Comment: Great let me know if you need any help or maybe connect on LinkedIn : https://www.linkedin.com/in/ghazniali95/

Answer (score 0):

try to create a common class name to all the items you want to be together, and use `flex:50%`

```css
.item {
  width: 100%
}

.root {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.root > div {
  flex: 50%; /* or - flex: 0 50% - or - flex-basis: 50% - */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="item">Content 1</div>
  <div class="item">Content 2</div>
  <div class="item">Content 3</div>
  <div class="item">Content 4</div>
</div>
```

something like that

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you want, but if your add `overflow: auto;` to the `#public-listings` element, this will *include* its floated child elements and therefore put the subsequent element *below*  it, preventing the described overlap.